# Discord.js Problem if (!userOrRole) throw new TypeError('INVALID_TYPE', 'parameter', 'User nor a Role');

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im writing a discord bot as my first project and this is my permissionOverwrites String.

```
    chan.edit({
                            name: `closed-${chan.name}`, permissionOverwrites: [{
                                id: client.users.cache.get(chan.topic), deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                            }, {
                                id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone, deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                            }, {
                                id: client.config.roleSupport, allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                            },],
                        })
```

Can someone tell me maybe why i get those errors?

```
C:\Users\plens\Documents\GitHub\trojanbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\PermissionOverwrites.js:184
    if (!userOrRole) throw new TypeError('INVALID_TYPE', 'parameter', 'User nor a Role');
                           ^

TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\plens\Documents\GitHub\trojanbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\PermissionOverwrites.js:184:28)
    at C:\Users\plens\Documents\GitHub\trojanbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildChannelManager.js:249:90
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at GuildChannelManager.edit (C:\Users\plens\Documents\GitHub\trojanbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildChannelManager.js:249:60)
    at TextChannel.edit (C:\Users\plens\Documents\GitHub\trojanbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\GuildChannel.js:275:32)
    at InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (C:\Users\plens\Documents\GitHub\trojanbot\events\interactionCreate.js:170:26)
    at InteractionCollector.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at InteractionCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\plens\Documents\GitHub\trojanbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:109:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INVALID_TYPE'
}
```

I use DJS V13 and maybe this is the Problem.

As im still learning i would be happy if someone can help me with this.

Comment: What do you expect `client.users.cache.get(chan.topic)` to be? What is `chan.topic`?

Comment: chan.topic is the users id. i set the users clientid as topic

Comment: Could you `console.log` these two (`client.users.cache.get(chan.topic)` and `chan.topic`) and paste the values here?

Comment: i get a undefined from some users and from others i get the ID. Im confused why it can only use it some times

Comment: const chan = guild.channels.cache.get(interaction.channelId);
thats the chan constante